# UIViewController Retaining in ARC

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, automatic-ref-counting, strong-references

I have a subclass of UIViewController -> MyPopUpViewController

```
@protocol MyPopUpViewController Delegate;
@interface MyPopUpViewController : UIViewController
{

}
@property (nonatomic, strong) id <MyPopUpViewControllerDelegate>  delegate;

-(IBAction) buttonPressed:(id)sender;
@end

@protocol MyPopUpViewControllerDelegate
-(void) popupButtonPressed: (MyPopUpViewController*)controller;
@end
```

I cannot have this MyPopUpViewController as an instance variable because this comes externally, and there could be many and multiple of these popups can be up.  So far I tried this, and it crashes on the delegate call due to not being retained:

MyMainViewController:

```
-(void)externalNotificationReceived: (NSString*) sentMessage
{    
    MyPopUpViewController *popupView = [[MyPopUpViewController alloc] init];
    popupView.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:popupView.view];

    [popupView setInfo :sentMessage :@"View" :@"Okay"];
    popupView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, -568, 320, 568);
    popupView.view.center = self.view.center;
}

-(void)popupButtonPressed:(MyPopUpViewController *)controller :(int)sentButtonNumber
{
    NSLog(@"Popup Delegate Called");

    [controller.view removeFromSuperview];
    controller.delegate = nil;
    controller = nil;
}
```

Once the popup comes up, and when the ok button is tapped, it crashes and never gets to that NSLog.  How can I change

MyPopUpViewController *popupView = [[MyPopUpViewController alloc] init];

..so it would retain without making it an instance variable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt with this line `[popupView setInfo :sentMessage :@"View" :@"Okay"];`

Comment: Yea... that line is probably problematic.  But also... how does `MyPopUpViewController.m` look?  Specifically, the method in which you're calling `popupButtonPressed:` on the delegate?

Comment: @nhgrif There is nothing wrong with the `setInfo:::` method other than the horrible name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be doing proper view controller containment by calling `addChildViewController:`.

```
- (void)externalNotificationReceived: (NSString*) sentMessage {    
    MyPopUpViewController *popupView = [[MyPopUpViewController alloc] init];
    popupView.delegate = self;

    [popupView setInfo :sentMessage :@"View" :@"Okay"];
    popupView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, -568, 320, 568);
    popupView.view.center = self.view.center;

    [self addChildViewController:popupView];    
    [self.view addSubview:popupView.view];
    [popupView didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

This will keep a proper reference to the view controller as well as properly pass various view controller events. Read about this in the docs for `UIViewController` and the "View Controller Programming Guide for iOS".

BTW - you should name your methods better. Example:

```
popupButtonPressed::
```

should be named:

```
popupButtonPressed:buttonNumber:
```

Comment: I voted in favour of this answer for the `addChildViewController:` comment, then got to the BTW and wished I could vote again. Proper method naming is essential.

Comment: WORKS GREAT! Thank you.  What's the proper way to remove the view and it's view controller in delegate?

Answer (score 1):

Usually delegates are weak-referenced instead of strong. I, myself, would name it something else as to not confuse other people.

Also, the following bit of code will have no effect:

```
-(void)popupButtonPressed:(MyPopUpViewController *)controller :(int)sentButtonNumber
{
    ...
    controller = nil;
}
```

the controller would be released (set to `nil`) automatically at the end of the scope.